# Вывести порядковый номер максимального элемента массива по кнопке

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

#pragma endregion
private: System::Void textBox1_TextChanged(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
}

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    double A[10]; 
    double max; 
    int i_max;
    int i;
    //описание переменных

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)//цикл ввода массива

    {

        A[i] = System::Convert::ToDouble(textBox1->Lines[i]);//ввод

    }
    max = A[0];
    i_max = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        if (A[i] > max)
        {
            max = A[i];
            i_max = i;
        }

    /*Вывод результата в Надпись*/

    label2->Text = "Наибольший массив " + System::Convert::ToString(max);
    label3->Text = "Порядковый номер наибольшего массива ";
}
```

};
}[image: Интерфейс проги]

Comment: Во-первых, исправьте форматирование. Во-вторых, подробнее опишите задачу и проблему